# Server load in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, database, performance, t-sql, ssis

I wonder which server (SQL Server 2008R2) "gives" resources (CPU, RAM) for computations, for Data Flow in SSIS. In my example:

> Server A: I run SSIS on it (using remote desktop connection) and
>   execute package
>
> Server B: This is my source (OLE DB source)
>
> Server C: This is my destination (OLE DB destination)

To which server I should connect (run SSIS package) to achieve best performance (all servers and load are close the same)?

Comment: Depends. Similar question from [dba.se](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/131519/2131)

Comment: Can you give me more details why it's depends?